# How can I play an ALAW file in a Java application?

Tags: java, file, audio

I need to be able to play ALAW files in a Java (desktop) application.
I've tried to follow the example at:

[How to play audio in Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708254/how-to-play-audio-in-java-application)

I've created a File object from the ALAW file (which exists, according to check) and sent that File to a method where the first thing that happens is this:

`AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);`

But this is where the execution stops, since I get this exception:

`javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file`

I see that there is a way to convert ALAW files if the check  `(ais.getFormat().getEncoding() == AudioFormat.Encoding.ALAW)` is `true`, but how can I get there if it's not even possible to create the AudioInputStream?

Anyone who has worked with ALAW files and has an idea of what I should do?

Is there a way to convert the ALAW files programmatically before calling `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file)`?

I really need to make this work!

Comment: Have you verified that the sound file is, indeed, an a-law formatted sound file?

Comment: Can you provide a link to an a-law sound file please, my google-fu has failed on this...

Comment: Yes. It has been created with Asterisk.

Answer (score 1):

Get existing file format from your `AudioInputStream`:
filepath is `String` with path to your file,which you obtain for example:

```
String filename="x.y";
File file = new File(filename);
String filepath=file.getCanonicalPath();
```

Then main conversion is done by:

```
AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(filepath));
AudioFormat format = inputStream.getFormat();
AudioInputStream convertedInputStream;
```

After that put condition, which checks if your file encoding is alaw or ulaw, and converts it to PCM which can be played by SoundCard:

```
if ((format.getEncoding() == AudioFormat.Encoding.ULAW) || (format.getEncoding() == AudioFormat.Encoding.ALAW))
AudioFormat tmp = new AudioFormat(
AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
format.getSampleRate(),
format.getSampleSizeInBits() * 2, 
format.getChannels(),
format.getFrameSize() * 2,
format.getFrameRate(), true);
convertedInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(tmp,inputStream);
format = tmp;}
```

This code will convert ALAW/ULAW format of your `AudioInputStream` to PCM_SIGNED

Answer (score 0):

JMF will help in this case. 
http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/java/archives/0503/decarmo/index.html

Comment: Yes, that seems possible, but I need a solution that's rather quick to implement and I'm not sure that this is. The playing of A-law files is just a small part of a component that also is quite small.